# Recursion? I understand the basics but have trouble understanding the flow of this code

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have recently taken my first steps to learning JavaScript. I'm following the FreeCodeCamp *['JavaScript Algorithms and Data Structures Certification'](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn)* track.

I'm really struggling to understand how recursion works and especially how it interacts with the stack. I understand some basic examples but am completely stuck on this example!

```
function countup(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}
console.log(countup(5)); // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

I understand that `count(n-1)` is calling the function again with an argument 1 less the original value of N but don't understand how it is **actually** working. Why assign to `const countArray`? why `return countArray` at the end.

Thank you!!

Comment: Perhaps replacing every call to `countup` with its whole code helps

Comment: Here's what I mean by that: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/b3n28pry/14/

Comment: @acdcjunior: you should make that into an answer, it's a great way to visualize this.

Comment: So I think I finally understand what is going on... I didn't understand what happened after the base case was hit. Am I right in thinking then when n = 0 the function returns an empty array. This then allows the previous call to finish executing and then return. Then the previous of that can then return etc etc.. Is that the right idea? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I made an illustration, hope it helps

[image]

Answer (score 0):

functions always return a value, even if you don't specify, it will return `undefined`. `countup` function in this case returns an array, either empty if the input is less than 1 or with items inside.

`countArray` is assigned to **result** of `countup(n - 1)` or in other words `countArray` will have the value of the invoked `countup` which will be an array.

Then countArray adds an item to it's array, and then `countup` returns that modified array.

When reading recursion code, start look at the base case, which is part that will meet the condition and therefore break to prevent infinite loop. The base case is when `n` is less than 1. It will return empty array.

```js
if (n < 1) {
  return [];
}
```

So let's say our input is 3, `n` = 3. Let's start from top of the code to bottom. The condition checking if n is less than 1 fails, so we jump to else logic.

```js
function countup(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {             VVVVVVV execution always pauses here until n is 0
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);

    /*** The rest is not run until other countups are done ***/
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
```

Once we run into invocation of `countup(n - 1)`, this will start a new execution stack where `n` now equals 2, so code will not continue running the rest of the logic, because it is now continuing on the new execution stack. Now the code is in loop of creating additional stacks until we hit the case where `n` is less than 1 as visually demonstrated below.

```
execution stack
countup(0) // stops looping because we pass the base case where n < 1. 
countup(1)
countup(2)
countup(3) // can't finish the logic until the other execution stacks on top of it are done
```

Now we can finally continue that logic where `countArray` pushes the current number on its array

```
countArray.push(n);
return countArray;
```

```
execution stack
countup(0) // returns empty array
countup(1)
countup(2)
countup(3)
```

```
execution stack
countup(1) // returns [ 1 ]
countup(2)
countup(3)
```

```
execution stack
countup(2) // returns [ 1, 2 ]
countup(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

`const countArray = countup(n - 1);` - assigns the value the `countup` returns.
so `countup` should return something.

You can add console logs to see what happens, but here is a walk through for `n=2`.

`countup(2)` - 2 > 1 so it continues to the else clause and calls `countup(1)`.
`countup(1)` - 1 = 1 so it continues to the else clause and calls `countup(0)`.
`countup(0)` - 0 < 1 so it returns an empty array `[]`.
`count(1)` continues at the point it stopped - so `const countArray = []`, at the next line it push (1) and returns `[1]`;
`count(2)` continues at the point it stopped - so `const countArray = [1]`, at the next line it push (2) and returns `[1,2]` as the final result of the recursive calls;

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There's a little trick I was taught, something they called "table evaluation" (which I don't know if it is a real thing), but it consists in evaluating the function call "by hand" (as if you were in a table with a pencil and a paper), replacing every function call with the function body and keep evaluating from that.

Okay, since the explanation can be a bit difficult, here's one stab at doing it online:

```js
// considering your function is this:
function countup(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}

// So the call to
console.log(countup(5));

// is the same as
console.log(if (5 < 1) {
  return [];
} else {
  const countArray = countup(5 - 1);
  countArray.push(5);
  return countArray;
})
// well, actually, sort of, because the "if" block is not an expression -- I mean, this is
// not valid code, but hopefully you'll catch the drift

// below I will just repeat the function code, I won't repeat the console.log() for clarity

// so the code that gets logged above is the same as (because we
// evaluated the if in the function body and therefore picked up just the else part)
const countArray = countup(4);
countArray.push(5);
return countArray;

// which is [replacing the countup(4) with the function body with n=4)
const countArray = (if (4 < 1) {
  return [];
} else {
  const countArray = countup(4 - 1);
  countArray.push(n);
  return countArray;
})
countArray.push(5);
return countArray;

// which is [evaluating the if]
const countArray = ({
  const countArray = countup(3);
  countArray.push(4);
  return countArray;
})
countArray.push(5);
return countArray;

// which is [countup(3)]
const countArray = ({
  const countArray = (if (3 < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup(3 - 1);
    countArray.push(3);
    return countArray;
  })
  countArray.push(4);
  return countArray;
})
countArray.push(5);
return countArray;

// which is
const countArray = ({
  const countArray = ({
    const countArray = countup(2);
    countArray.push(3);
    return countArray;
  })
  countArray.push(4);
  return countArray;
})
countArray.push(5);
return countArray;

// which is
const countArray = ({
  const countArray = ({
    const countArray = (if (2 < 1) {
      return [];
    } else {
      const countArray = countup(2 - 1);
      countArray.push(2);
      return countArray;
    })
    countArray.push(3);
    return countArray;
  })
  countArray.push(4);
  return countArray;
})
countArray.push(5);
return countArray;

// which is
const countArray = ({
  const countArray = ({
    const countArray = ({
      const countArray = countup(1);
      countArray.push(2);
      return countArray;
    })
    countArray.push(3);
    return countArray;
  })
  countArray.push(4);
  return countArray;
})
countArray.push(5);
return countArray;

// which is
const countArray = ({
  const countArray = ({
    const countArray = ({
      const countArray = (if (1 < 1) {
        return [];
      } else {
        const countArray = countup(1 - 1);
        countArray.push(1);
        return countArray;
      })
      countArray.push(2);
      return countArray;
    })
    countArray.push(3);
    return countArray;
  })
  countArray.push(4);
  return countArray;
})
countArray.push(5);
return countArray;

// which is
const countArray = ({
  const countArray = ({
    const countArray = ({
      const countArray = ({
        const countArray = countup(0);
        countArray.push(1);
        return countArray;
      })
      countArray.push(2);
      return countArray;
    })
    countArray.push(3);
    return countArray;
  })
  countArray.push(4);
  return countArray;
})
countArray.push(5);
return countArray;

// which is
const countArray = ({
  const countArray = ({
    const countArray = ({
      const countArray = ({
        const countArray = (if (0 < 1) {
          return [];
        } else {
          const countArray = countup(0 - 1);
          countArray.push(0);
          return countArray;
        })
        countArray.push(1);
        return countArray;
      })
      countArray.push(2);
      return countArray;
    })
    countArray.push(3);
    return countArray;
  })
  countArray.push(4);
  return countArray;
})
countArray.push(5);
return countArray;

// which is (now finally the first branch of the if...)
const countArray = ({
  const countArray = ({
    const countArray = ({
      const countArray = ({
        const countArray = (if (true) {
          return [];
        })
        countArray.push(1);
        return countArray;
      })
      countArray.push(2);
      return countArray;
    })
    countArray.push(3);
    return countArray;
  })
  countArray.push(4);
  return countArray;
})
countArray.push(5);
return countArray;

// which is
const countArray = ({
  const countArray = ({
    const countArray = ({
      const countArray = ({
        const countArray = [];
        countArray.push(1);
        return countArray;
      })
      countArray.push(2);
      return countArray;
    })
    countArray.push(3);
    return countArray;
  })
  countArray.push(4);
  return countArray;
})
countArray.push(5);
return countArray;

// which is
const countArray = ({
  const countArray = ({
    const countArray = ({
      const countArray = ({
        return [1]; // was [].push(1)
      })
      countArray.push(2);
      return countArray;
    })
    countArray.push(3);
    return countArray;
  })
  countArray.push(4);
  return countArray;
})
countArray.push(5);
return countArray;

// which is
const countArray = ({
  const countArray = ({
    const countArray = ({
      const countArray = [1];
      countArray.push(2);
      return countArray;
    })
    countArray.push(3);
    return countArray;
  })
  countArray.push(4);
  return countArray;
})
countArray.push(5);
return countArray;

// which is
const countArray = ({
  const countArray = ({
    const countArray = ({
      return [1, 2]; // was [1].push(2)
    })
    countArray.push(3);
    return countArray;
  })
  countArray.push(4);
  return countArray;
})
countArray.push(5);
return countArray;

// which is
const countArray = ({
  const countArray = ({
    const countArray = [1, 2];
    countArray.push(3);
    return countArray;
  })
  countArray.push(4);
  return countArray;
})
countArray.push(5);
return countArray;

// which is
const countArray = ({
  const countArray = ({
    return [1, 2, 3]; // was [1, 2].push(3)
  })
  countArray.push(4);
  return countArray;
})
countArray.push(5);
return countArray;

// which is
const countArray = ({
  const countArray = [1, 2, 3];
  countArray.push(4);
  return countArray; // was [1, 2].push(3)
})
countArray.push(5);
return countArray;

// which is
const countArray = ({
  return [1, 2, 3, 4]; // was [1, 2, 3].push(4)
})
countArray.push(5);
return countArray;

// which is
const countArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
countArray.push(5);
return countArray;

// which is
[1, 2, 3, 4].push(5);
return countArray;

// which is (bringing the console.log back)
console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some context to my answer:

Recursion is a strategy for solving problems by defining the problem in terms of itself. 
In programming, recursion means a function definition will include an invocation of the function within its own body. Here’s a pseudo-code example:

Consider this pseudo-code of your question:
Question: print all positive numbers between 1 and a given number `n` for e.g if `n` is `3` 
print `1 2 3`

Solution:

1. List item
2. Check if `n` is less than 1

   1. If it is, our answer is `0` (because there can't be any positive numbers between it and 1)
   2. If it is not
   3. Subtract 1 from `n` (to give us a new `n`)
3. Check new `n` to see if it is less than 1

   1. If it is, our answer is `n`
   2. If it is not
   3. Subtract 1 from new `n` (to give us a new `n`)
4. Check newer n to see
   ....

As you can see there's a part of this solution that keeps repeating itself in itself, this is a simple representation of recursion, where we implement a block of code continually, testing different cases (by modifying the parameter e.g subtracting a value from it) till we get our required result.

Following this pattern, since we want to get all the numbers between 1 and 5 we start at 5, checking if it is less than one, if it is not we add it to our array of all the values between 1 and 5, then we reduce 5 and check again until we are less than one, then we return the array

How we handle this in Javascript is by **declaring** the function in the function's body (by assigning it to a variable) so that we can call it with modified parameters (to test for different cases)
in this case `countArray` with a modified form of our initial value

```js
...
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
...
```

Then we perform our logic on the function with modified parameters, in this case

```
...
    countArray.push(n);
...
```

Finally, we return the newest value (which ends our test) in this case it is the final array

```
...
    return countArray;
...
```